# cocoapods depend on specific scheme

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an old framework that can has a specific scheme that is shared so Carthage can build it.  I want to use that scheme with Cocoapods.  Is that possible?

As a side note, does pod spec lint build a specific scheme or does it basically try to run xcodebuild with the source_files you specify in the podspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pod spec lint` and `podspec`s in general generate their own Xcode targets and schemes.

Typically, the `podspec` specifies the files and build information for libraries that get aggregated with an app's Xcode project to create an Xcode workspace.

So, as far as I know, the answer to your question is no.